# is there a way to check if there is text between the nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below 2 different XML Cases.

**Case1**

```
<para><content-style font-style="bold">1/3</content-style> This is text</para>
```

**Case2**

```
<para>This is text <content-style font-style="bold">1/3</content-style></para>
```

i'm using the template match as below

```
<xsl:template match="para[content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]]">
```

but as per this match, both the cases mentioned above are satisfied, i want only first case to be caught ignoring the second case.

please let me know how can i get this done.

Thanks

Comment: And what exactly _is_ the difference that makes the rule? That the text starts or ends with a whitespace character or that the text node is before or after the child `content-style` element?

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, The text node is before and after the child makes the rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `matches()`. If the rule is whether the `content-style` element is the first child node of `para`, match for

```
para[node()[position() = 1 and self::content-style]]
```

Assuming the following input document, where both cases are present:

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <para><content-style font-style="bold">1/3</content-style>YES</para>
    <para>NO <content-style font-style="bold">1/3</content-style></para>
</root>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="para[node()[position() = 1 and self::content-style]]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<para>
   <content-style font-style="bold">1/3</content-style>YES</para>
```