# XSLT match both first and second child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<para><page num="42"/><content-style font-style="bold">2/1/4</content-style></para>
```

Here i'm creating a template and trying to match both the first and second child as below.

```
<xsl:template match="para[node()[position() = 2 and self::content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')] and (position() = 1 and self::page)]]">
```

Here when i try it like

```
<xsl:template match="para[node()[(position() = 1 and self::page)]]">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="para[node()[position() = 2 and self::content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]]]">
```

the match is correctly being called, but when i combine as shown in top, it is not working,

I need to perform some tasks based on this match, please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Another apparently random question, and you [did not exactly heed my advice about `matches()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28195409/1987598). You are saying you'd like to match child elements, but all of the templates you show match `para` elements. Do you perhaps mean: match `para` elements if `page` is the first child, and `content-style` the second? Please add an [input XML to the question, and a full XSLT stylesheet, and the output you expect](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - because [I'm not sure what you're after](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Well a matched node can not have `position() = 1` and `position() = 2`, so you will need to use `or` and not `and`. Or simply write two patterns in the match attribute

```
<xsl:template match="para[node()[1][self::page]]
                     | para[node()[2][self::content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]]]">...</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add that this match pattern does not require `page` and `content-style` to appear in the same `para` element - as they do in the OP's code snippet?

Comment: Part of the question asks how to combine `<xsl:template match="para[node()[(position() = 1 and self::page)]]">` and `<xsl:template match="para[node()[position() = 2 and self::content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]]]">`, that's what I tried to show. I understand that the first part of the question can be interpreted in a different way but as my suggestion was accepted, I hope it does what was asked for.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, sorry for the delayed reply, i was trying to combine both using `and` but not `or` and it gives me error as `unexpected token and` can you please let me know where am i going wrong?

Comment: We can only tell where you are going wrong if you provide a minimal but complete code sample together with exact information about the XSLT processor and the error message you get. Inside of a `match` pattern you can combine various patterns with `|`, in that case it is simply shortcut for writing several templates with a single match pattern.